# Automatic screen cast(MediaRouter/Chromecast) on Android or other HDMI display alternative

Tags: android, wifi, wireless, chromecast, hdmi

We have a custom Android device with WiFi/Bluetooth antennae that we intend to operate without direct user interaction (like a router).  Normal operation doesn't require any visible display, but troubleshooting or setup will.  The device has an HDMI port for connecting to external screens but no built in display.

While we can plug in to an HDMI TV out of the box, the device will generally be in locations where big screens are inconvenient.  We would like to make it convenient to display onto laptops or other small screens; the only other ports we have are USB-A receptacles, so I'm assuming any solution will be network (wired or wireless) based.

Edit: I had originally been looking at Chromecast before realizing it was an HDMI plug. Is there a simple way to cast to computers or is a hardware solution likely to be the most viable?

I'm still in the planning phases so will post more information as I run in to it. Am just trying to avoid writing a bunch of code that won't ever work; any alternative suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

*Previous text:
Does anyone have suggestions on how to approach this?  My initial research led me towards using [MediaRouter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html) to connect to a [Chromecast dongle](http://www.google.com/chrome/devices/chromecast/) (Device will run Android 4.4.2 ), but I'm unsure if the API gives enough control to find and connect without a display in the first place. I could only find examples of users selecting what to route to, and didn't see any proximity information in [MediaRouter.RouteInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaRouter.RouteInfo.html) to base make a decision based on (a la RSSI in Bluetooth). Finally, I wasn't sure if [this supported devices list](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6059461) meant a custom device wouldn't work.*

Comment: what was your solution in the end?

Comment: At the time I think we determined there weren't any off-the-shelf solutions that did what we wanted, and so we settled for HDMI. A lot changed since then though, and while I'm sure they all have problems there seem to be [numerous](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-cast-an-Android-screen-on-a-laptop) [options](https://www.google.com/amp/s/techwiser.com/cast-your-android-screen/amp/). It's also even harder to find screens without HDMI now than then.